# How to user filter() pit point return from $.post

Tags: jquery, post

i have a problem and i'm not sure where it is, i have a script that posts data to a php file, and gets the HTML output, then i want to filter it to only use one part of the page.

My script looks like this

```
var newsletter_form  = $(".newsletter_signup_form");
var newsletter_firstname  = $("#newsletter_firstname");
var newsletter_surname  = $("#newsletter_surname");
var newsletter_email  = $("#newsletter_email");

newsletter_form.submit(function(){
    $.post("news_signup.php", $(".newsletter_signup_form").serialize(), function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
        var newletter_messages = $( response ).filter( ".messages" );
        $( ".newsletter_messages" ).html( newletter_messages );
    }).done( function() { console.log( "DONE" ); } );
    return false;
});
```

And my PHP file is like this, it's basic and doesn't use any PHP yet I'm just trying to get the response (This is also what the response looks like when i console.log it)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="newsletter_form">
   <form action="" class="newsletter_signup_form">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <input type="text" name="newsletter_firstname" id="newsletter_firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="text" name="newsletter_surname" id="newsletter_surname" placeholder="Surname" />
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="email" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" placeholder="Email Address" />
     </li>
     <li>
      <button name="join_btn">Join</button>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </form>
   <div class="messages">
    Something
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is the HTML for to output the response

```
<div class="newsletter_messages">
      Loading....
</div>
```

So i want to get ".messages" from the response and update ."newsletter_messages" with the response.

The console.log shows me that the full HTML is being returned to the Javascript but when i filter and try to update the HTML it just does blank.

I feel like I'm not using either the html() method of the filter() properly. I am still learning Jquery. Also, i have another post method that does the same thing only for a different for, that method works just fine with a filter() and html() call. For this example i have commented all of the other Jquery code just in case it was messing with it but still nothing.

Can anyone spot it or point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: What are you getting as response??Can you fiddle the code?

Comment: Well the response is the same as the php file. I'll try and get a jfiddle going now. @Joke_Sense10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jquery find() function instead of filter. Filter will check for the selector given the response, it will not go through the nested elements.

Comment: That is perfect! This is the problem when learning things for yourself is sometimes you can't see the simple solution! Thanks again for the help. One other thing, theoretically, would filter would if i narrowed down the search. For example instead of filter(".messages") maybe something like filter(".newsletter_form", ".messages") or something a long those lines? I'm not suggesting i'll use this but i'd just like to know.

Comment: you can test what goes through filter of several data and selectors, if you call filter(function(index,theElem){console.log(theElem);});   This calls your function while filtering and if it returns true then the filter is met and the element included otherwise it does not. http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex